# A rigorous proof that is not rigorous

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can we prove $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$ is true for all $x$? We can do it "algebraically", but we can also do it by testing:

$x=0$ true

$x=1$ true

$x=2$ true

If it's not always true, then it's polynomial with degree $2$. But deg$(P)=$deg$(Q)=n$ and $P(a_i)=Q(a_i) \forall 1\le i\le n+1$, then $P(n)=Q(n)$ and the equation is always true.

Are there examples/explanations about "testing" if an equation is true?

Comment: `then it's polynomial with degree 2` Once you formally justify this `then` the rest is a valid proof. The technique of using that a polynomial of degree at most $n$ that has $\gt n$ roots must be identically zero is well established. `since two different parabolas can't intersect 3 times` Careful there, since that's not true in general, think at the case where the axes of symmetry are not parallel.

Comment: @dxiv I edited. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score -3):

You could try Mathematical Induction:

First you verify x=1 is true
Then assume that x=n is true
then prove that x=n+1 is true 
    by algebraic manipulation of x=n for your equation
    to get something equivalent to x=n+1

Comment: This doesn't work for functions over the real line.